# fibonacci doesn't output 0

Tags: python, fibonacci

I wrote a short code which outputs the first n numbers of the Fibonacci sequence where n is the value of the passed parameter and each number is printed in a new line. 
My problem is that the output isn't starting at 0, it starts at 1. How do I also get the 0 in the output?

```py
def fibonacci(n):
    fib1 = 0
    fib2 = 1
    for x in range(0,n):
        print("%d\n" %(fib2), end = " ")
        next = fib1 + fib2 
        fib1 = fib2
        fib2 = next
```

So this is the output, why are the numbers after the first one moved in?
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCptd.png)

Comment: you can explicitly check for a `n==0` and print separately, that's one option.

Comment: Print fib1 alone before entering the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def fibonacci(n):
    fib1 = 0
    fib2 = 1
    for x in range(0,n):
        print("%d\n" %(fib1), end = " ")
        next = fib1 + fib2 
        fib1 = fib2
        fib2 = next
```

Simple print `fib1` instead of `fib2` at `line #5`
How do you expect output `0` at start if you printed `fib2` which is `1`

Comment: thank you, stupid mistake! lol But another question: why does my output write the 0 and the 1 straight among themselves but all following numbers moved into?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    fib1 = 0
    fib2 = 1
    for x in range(0, n):
        print("%d" %(fib1))
        fib1, fib2 = fib2, fib1 + fib2
```

Alternatively, you can just switch the values of `fib1` and `fib2` without messing with your code any more.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in other examples you can solve your problem .. I am sharing few more ways to do it.. shorter code

```
 def fibonacci_fun(n):
  a, b = 0, 1
  for x in range(2, n):
    print('%s' % a)
    a, b = b, a+b

 fibonacci_fun(n)
```

another way using while loop

```
def fibonacci(n):
  a, b = 0, 1
  while a <= n:
    print(a)
    a, b = b, a+b

fibonacci(n)
```